# GAE "for each" in template?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I'm using `for each` in template of GAE (which uses Django's template language)

```
{% for blog_info in blog_archive %}                         
  {{ blog_info.time|date:"M Y" }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I just want to loop only one time, I try to do like this:

```
{% for blog_info in blog_archive %}     
  {{ blog_info.time|date:"M Y" }}
  {% break %}
{% endfor %}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'each time' here? Do you only want to process the first item, if so, why are you using a loop?

Answer (score 2):

The `{% for %}` template tag does not support `{% break %}`. In the template, you can access the first item of a list `var` using `{{ var.0 }}`.

In your case, try:

```
{{ blog_archive.0.time|date:"M Y" }}
```

Comment: why would you access the first element in a list like a property? don't think this would work. ...or is this template specific?

Comment: That's how you do index lookups in the Django template language. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) for more details.

Comment: @aschmid00: the OP appears to be asking a question about [Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/), not Python. Alasdair’s code is correct. (Django templates are deliberately not Python.)

Comment: ur right. missed the part mentioning django templates. removing my answer.

Comment: I'd like to try,thanks Qin("Qin is kind of Chinese greeting, that means dear or kind of intimate relationship").: )